# ISO 8583 Message Giving Timeout Error in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, iso8583, banking, jpos

I'm scripting for ISO Messages using JMeter to do Load Testing. I have used the ISO 8583 Sampler and connection configuration. All the data field by field is mapped correctly including the MTI (Field 0). But the issue is that the request is not being sent to the server from the JMeter. It just keep on giving the timeout issue and I'm getting no response against it. I've seen the request and validated it format from the implementer himself and he says that the format is correct. Can anyone help to trouble shoot this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Why am I getting timeouts?](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-iso8583#why-am-i-getting-timeouts) documentation section,

> **Why am I getting timeouts?**
>
> The three common reasons for response timeouts are:
>
> 1. The sampler does not receive any response.
> 2. The sampler does receive a response but fails to unpack it.
> 3. The sampler does receive a response and unpacks it but no request can be matched.
>
> The debug log should contain Channel output similar to the following:
>
> ```
> 2022-02-22 12:34:56,789 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (channel/HOSTNAME:POST) [send] Out: 0800 000001
> 2022-02-22 12:34:56,987 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (channel/HOSTNAME:POST) [receive]  In: 0810 000001
> ```
>
> If only the first log line is present, no response was received (case 1 above). It is likely that the request is incorrectly formed and the remote system discarded it, so checking its logs/traces may be helpful. Double-check the Packager Configuration file! This defines how a request is packed (or response is unpacked) before (after) it goes over the wire.
>
> If both lines are present, a response was in fact received (cases 2 and 3 above).
>
> If the second log line instead contains an error like the following, then the response failed to unpack (case 2 above). Double-check the Packager Configuration file!
>
> ```
> 2022-02-22 12:34:56,987 ERROR n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (channel/HOSTNAME:POST) [receive] org.jpos.iso.SOMECLASSNAMEHERE: Problem unpacking field ...
> ```
>
> If the second log line contains no error then it is likely that the plugin did not find a matching request (case 3 above). Double-check the Mux Settings! These define MTI values and message fields that are used for matching, and the default settings may not work.

In order to [increase JMeter's logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the ISO 8583 sampler add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="nz.co.breakpoint.jmeter.iso8583" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change.

Also make sure that you can reach the target server host/port from the machine where JMeter is running using a [telnet client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_clients) or equivalent.

Comment: Thank You for the logging information. It turned out that the request was sent to the server but the server returned <peer-disconnect>. So it was a server side issue. Any idea what this issue might be about?

Comment: Now do the same on the server side

Comment: 2022-02-22 12:34:56,789 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (channel/HOSTNAME:POST) [connect] try 0                                                                                                             
2022-02-22 12:34:56,789 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (channel/HOSTNAME:POST) [send] Some ISO Message
2022-02-22 12:34:56,987 DEBUG n.c.b.j.i.Q2: (channel/HOSTNAME:POST) [receive]  <peer disconnect> any idea what is the issue here?